# How to import a d3 v4 / v5 module into a Node project but keep the D3 v3 namespace style (d3.)?

Tags: node.js, d3.js, webpack, es6-modules, rollupjs

I want to import the d3.selection es6 module into a project that is being bundled with rollup (including the common.js plugin).

So I do:

`import {select, selectAll} from "d3-selection";`

But now I have to write d3.. like it's some other language.

```
select('.classname').. etc..
```

I'd rather write

```
d3.select()
```

How can I keep that d3 namespace with prototype methods like select, min, max etc. That way it's all d3 dot whatever. d3.select etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've learned that one way to do this is to just use d3-require to create the namespace, then export as a module.

```
d3.require("d3-array", "d3-color").then(d3 => {
  console.log(d3.range(360).map(h => d3.hsl(h, 1, 0.5)));
});
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's one way to do it:

```
import {select, selectAll} from 'd3-selection';
import {scaleOrdinal, scaleLinear} from 'd3-scale';
// etc.

const d3 = {select, selectAll, scaleOrdinal, scaleLinear}
//
const svg = d3.select('svg');
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [mdn docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) you won't be able to place both in the same namespace, things you could do are

```
import * as d3 from "d3-selection";
```

Or since you are only importing select and selectAll

```
import {select as d3.select, selectAll as D3.selectAll} from "d3-selection";
```

Comment: but then if I import d3-array... like  import {min as d3.min} from "d3-array"; won't this cause a conflict? the namespace is so broken :(

Comment: Yes it will. Ya iwish you could have multiple imports under the same namespace. You could alternatively create a custom D3 bundpe with just the aspects you want then import that.

Comment: that seems to be Mike's advice but.. isn't really consistent with how code is written.

Comment: I would agree. Unfortunately u less they decide to change the standard we're stuck with creating our own bundles.

Comment: when I try this I get `Unexpected token, expected ","`  which is d3.select